# What is the cost-effective way to host static web application in azure in private network

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

I need to host a static web application in azure in a private network.

Currently, I'm using web app premium to host static web applications in a private network. But it an expensive, I need to know is there a cost-effective way to deploy static web applications in a private network

Answer (score 1):

Either

[Azure Static Web Apps Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/private-endpoint)

or

[Static Website Hosting in Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)